# Как в HashMap увеличить значение числа

Tags: java

Как `HashMap<String, Integer> map` увеличить значение числа, например, я вставил в `map` значение: `map.put("example", 5);` и как его по ключу увеличить?

Comment: так - `map.put("example", map.get("example") + 1)`, или так - `map.computeIfPresent("example", (k, v) -> ++v)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получаем по ключу значение, что-то делаем с ним и вставляем обратно

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Primer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> mymap = new HashMap<>();
        // изменяем значение в переменную
        mymap.put("example", 5);
        int x = mymap.get("example") * 2;
        System.out.println(x);

        // извлекаем значение ключа в переменную, изменяем ее,
        // вставляем обратно
        mymap.put("example2", 8);
        int y = mymap.get("example2");
        y = y + 1;
        mymap.put("example2", y);
        System.out.println(mymap.get("example2");
    }   
}
```

Вывод программы:

10

9

Answer (score 1):

Хочу предоставить более понятный пример:

```html
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Example {
    static HashMap<String, Integer>map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public static void main(String... args){
        map.put("example", 5);  //Положили значение #1
        map.put("example", map.get("example")+1); //Перезаписали его, добавив +1
    }
}
```